# It's possible to program using RoR in Xcode?? If yes how should I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode

I'm new to programming and I've not understood if I can use RoR in X code or if I can only program throw Swift.

Answer (score 0):

It´s perfectly possible to program Ruby in XCode of course,

You can use the built in git support, .rb files will be automatically recognised for being ruby, you will have syntax highlighting and **auto completion** (just tested it). You can make use of the project features too, managing multiple source files etc.

Just in case: Source type can be adjusted e.g. in the right sidebar 2nd dropdown named "Type".

I use xcode for c++, python and embedded development. It´s very customisable.

Comment: Thanks you'e been really useful!